# How to return function constructor object property on the current function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Please see my code first,

```js
   //simple function expression
    let
        app = function (){
            return new app.fn.init();
        } 

    //need to get the init method
    app.fn = app.prototype;

    app.fn.init = function(){
       return 'I am on';
    }
    
    console.log ( app() )
//return the object but I need 'I am on'
```

It's normal we all knew it. But I need to get this `init()`. I am not good at js so please can someone help me to get this init. How can I do something in this init function?

Comment: What do you try to achieve with that? And when do you get that error message?

Comment: I want to make a mini-js-library for some features. I also want to learn how jquery has done this stuff. please help me to get it.

Comment: Side note: FWIW, I recommend not reassigning the `prototype` property on constructor functions. Instead, change `app.fn = app.prototype = {}` to just `app.fn = app.prototype;`. If you're putting things in the `{}`, change it to `app.fn = Object.assign(app.prototype, {/*...stuff here...*/});`

Comment: FWIW, the way jQuery does this, which dates from 2006 when ES3 was the latest JavaScript standard, probably isn't the way you should do it in 2020, seven language updates later.

Comment: You need to create a [mcve]  that reproduces that error message, reverting the snippet to be not executable, does not change the fact that it is not clear when that error occures.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, I just forgot about our ES6 features.

Comment: Your `init` function, with the `return 'I am on'` is called, but as you return a primitive it is ignored. If you would return an object then this object would be logged. But the need to do something like that indicates a design flaw of what you want to create.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do this.
**Method 1**:
You access the `app.fn.init` function.

```js
let app = function (){
  return new app.fn.init();
} 
app.fn = app.prototype;
app.fn.init = function(){
  return 'I am on';
}
// calling app.fn.init directly 
console.log ( app.fn.init() );
// Logs: 'I am on';
```

**Method 2**: You change the app function to not return a new instance but the return value of `app.fn.init`:

```js
let app = function (){
  // Notice that the 'new' is gone.
  return app.fn.init();
} 
app.fn = app.prototype;
app.fn.init = function(){
  return 'I am on';
} 
console.log ( app() );
// Logs: 'I am on';
```

Both methods give the same result ("I am on"), choose the one that is easier or suits your purpose.

**ADDRESSING COMMENT:**

```js
function calledWithNew(number) {
  // Changing the 'this'
  this.number = number;
  this.add = function(n) {
    this.number += n;
  }
  
  /* About 'this' when called with new:
      It's an object, all the modifications above will change 'this';
      gets returned automatically.
  */
}
function enhanced() {
  // Called with 'new'
  return new calledWithNew(9);
  // returning an instance of calledWithNew, an object.
}
console.log(enhanced());
/*
  Stack Overflow logs the object: {
    "number": 9,
    "add" : function (n) {
      this.number += n;
    }
  }
  Browser logs: calledWithNew {number: 9, add: f(n)}
*/
```

Comment: But as I know jQuery does the same thing as my code. They return with new objects. I want to know how they have done it. They also don't call it like jQuery.fn.init() just jQuery() how?
<
// Define a local copy of jQuery
var jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
        // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
        return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
    },

Comment: When you call a function with "new", it's going to return the 'this' in the context of the function. See my Edit.

Comment: I understand that. But jQuery does the same thing, they return with "new" and also get it using only jQuery() not jQuery.fn.init(). I just want to understand how they have done it.

Comment: They can. They are trying to return an object with the `jQuery.fn.init`. You try to return a primitive string. But the string is never returned because functions called with 'new' always return an object, (usually 'this').

Comment: Now I get it. Thank you so much and so sorry for my stupid chaining question.

Comment: Why not? Can you help me one more question plz, You know you can. Let's talk on social sites like FB plz. I am new in js

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in what you return from the function. If you return an object - like jQuery does - then this object is the one you get from the `new` call:

```js
//simple function expression
let
  app = function() {
    return new app.fn.init();
  }

//need to get the init method
app.fn = app.prototype;

app.fn.init = function() {
  return {prop: 'I am on'};
}

console.log(app())
```

Comment: This is also right. But I can't accept both answer but the first one. Thanks for share this